# Как изменить версию python, использующуюся в SUDO APT INSTALL?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

На моем устройстве две версии Python: 3.7 и 3.8.

Пытаюсь установить модуль `python-opencv`, используя в командой строке это `sudo apt install python3-opencv` и это работает, **НО** данный модуль устанавливается к Python версии 3.8, а мне нужен этот модуль на версии 3.7. Пытался решить эту проблему с помощью `alternatives`, теперь при написании `python3` в командной строке открывается Python версии 3.7, но команда `sudo apt install python3-opencv` всё еще устанавливает модуль для версии 3.8. Помогите, пожалуйста, защита курсовой уже завтра..

Comment: Используйте `conda`. Ставя библиотеки в системный Питон вы рано или поздно убъете систему.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете попробовать установить opencv как библиотеку питона:

```bash
python3.7 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Или (раз вы используете `alternatives`)

```bash
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, в данный момент протестировать его не могу, так как похоже накрылась СД карта, а все магазины ночью обычно закрыты.